# Pexpect eats bash prompt

Tags: python, shell, expect, pexpect

This expect script launches a bash shell that includes the prompt:

```
#! /usr/bin/env expect

spawn -noecho "bash"

expect "$ "

send "echo 'Hello, "

interact
```

e.g. `user@host:/path/to/working/directory$ echo 'Hello,`

I tried doing the same thing with [Pexpect](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('bash')

index = child.expect("\$ ")

child.send("echo 'Hello, ")

child.interact()
```

However, it swallows the prompt and only shows `echo 'Hello,`.
I can force `bash` to repaint with `child.sendcontrol('l')`,
but this only works for some shells;
[`dash`](http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/),
for example, does not support it.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 11 2014, 08:58:12) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pexpect
>>> pexpect.__version__
'3.2'
```

Comment: Set `logfile` to `sys.stdout` to echo everything to standard output. `send()` and `sendline()` are different. There is an unclosed single quote in the command. Use `expect_exact()` to match non-regex string.

Comment: It's been more than a week with no answer, so I'm opening a bug report.

Comment: https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/184

Comment: your expectations might be incorrect e.g., I don't expect that anything that happens before the `.interact()` call is printed unless `.logfile*` is set.

Comment: Setting `child.logfile = sys.stdout` does display the prompt, but it has the side effect of doubling every input. Setting the logfile to an external file shows the prompt in that file, but not on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bug, pexpect does indeed "suppress" up until interact, as this is intended, it doesn't know you would later call interact.

Anyway. If you want to see the prompt (and anything else) printed up until the match, just print it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('bash')
index = child.expect_exact("$ ")
print(child.before + child.match, end='')
child.interact()
```

(Be careful about matching `$`, not all prompts have them. If you're going to use this for any portability, you should take care to force-set PS1 and so on, an example in the `pexpect.replwrap.bash()` function: https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/pexpect/replwrap.py#L108-113 )

It has been a very long time since I used the original tcl/expect, but I seem to recall that it *implies* duplicating all child program output to the parent process: it always duplicates stdout, which is why the tcl/expect version doesn't require printing before interact to "see" what was given up until `interact` is called.

https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/184#issuecomment-78819460

Comment: Please provide some explanation.  See [answer].

Comment: I migrated the complete explanation over from GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

As J.F. Sebastian indicated, there is an alternative:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import pexpect
import sys
child = pexpect.spawn('bash')
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout
index = child.expect_exact("$ ")
child.interact()
```